# request does not force a reload from the server

Tags: node.js, express

So basically I want to query the blockchain to find the moment when an unconfirmed transaction comes through for a particular bitcoin address.

I have a Node script that is re-requesting a page every second.

```
request('http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/unconfirmed/1CCQCkmcHFTfgctthi3fBB5UJ1U6ejjBPh', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
```

When the blockchain updates, this Node script is not picking it up. Viewing, say,   https://blockchain.info/address/1CCQCkmcHFTfgctthi3fBB5UJ1U6ejjBPh I see the transaction has been picked up by the blockchain.

If I enter http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/unconfirmed/1CCQCkmcHFTfgctthi3fBB5UJ1U6ejjBPh into a browser and push enter, it shows the updated unconfirmed transactions. And somehow that triggers something on blockr.io, because then suddenly my Node script picks up the change. Whereas it doesn't seem to running by itself.

So what I'm asking, is how to force a refresh on that URL from the Node script?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by 'server updates'?

Comment: A new unconfirmed transaction comes through. I can check on other sites like blockchain.info to double check.

Comment: I don't get it... Can you paste more code?

Comment: Can you try sending cache control headers?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was as Yalamber suggested..

```
var options = {
    url: apiToCheck,
    headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
```